# Custom Gutenberg Blocks automatically wrapping <img/> with <figure>

Tags: wordpress, image, figure, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to write a custom Gutenberg slider. I have this in my edit() and save() functions:

```
    <div>
     { attributes.images.map( function ( imageData ) {
      return(

      <figure>
        <img
         src={imageData.sizes.full.url}
        />
      </figure>
       )
      }, 
     })
</div>
```

When I save, the front end looks fine, but my backend gives me an error, tand when I click on resolve blocks it shows me this:

[image]

Is it because I added multiple to my  element?

Comment: I sometimes have the same problem when saving, with a single image.

Comment: Kindly, Share the full code. So that we can pinpoint the error. Most likely, your HTML nodes on edit function is not matching up with save HTML nodes

Comment: It was just the way I was storing the meta infos that was causing trouble. Should have put them in an array. You can check it out in my repo below: https://github.com/illmatic6514/slider-block

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It was just a query error in the attributes. Gutenberg seems to put figure tags around <img /> whenever there is an attribute error.